# Keeping a Hero Prisoner in Parallel?

Tags: prison

I had an idea for a story where there are two worlds in parallel, mirroring each other, one about our level of technology, one pre-industrial. Now, there's a hero that's been captured by the bad guys in both worlds. But the bad guys in both worlds have a problem. They need to keep the hero alive for their plans, but they want to make absolutely certain that they can't escape while keeping them relatively unharmed (except maybe muscular degeneration from lack of exercise/movement). Assuming that they can only use materials/methods possible in the real world at the time period (no magic, etc.) how would they go about this?

Edit: Note that the bad guys want to keep the hero close.

Comment: I;m assuming the hero and bad guys can shift between the two separate worlds? Can you give some more details on the parallel worlds and why they would make containment difficult?

Comment: I don't get it. What's so difficult in keeping a prisoner locked up in a room? They did have prisons in pre-industrial times; you may have heard of the Tower of London, of the Mamertine prison of ancient Rome...

Comment: I am assuming that the hero can travel back and forth between these two times, otherwise we can just lock him/her in a room,

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper we all know what they say about assuming, better for the OP to clarify how the parallel worlds factors in

Comment: I feel like your question is both extremely broad as well as asking about how to craft your story rather than how to craft your world. You have given rather little detail about the situation the protagonist is put in as well as no aim for what a solution to a problem might look like. I recommend using the Sandbox on Worldbuilding Meta to improve your question and help you get the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Throw them on a deserted island far into the ocean with plenty of food, and with a chain to a heavy iron ball on one foot.

If the hero can travel back and forth between these two eras, then simply pick a deserted island that is still deserted in the modern era. It will not lose its usefulness even if the time changes. There are plenty to choose from.

Trapping someone in preindustrial times isn't any different than trapping them today. We also have to be realistic. Just because a person is a "hero" doesn't mean they have super powers. Being stranded on a desert island should be adequate. The food is to make sure they don't starve, and the heavy iron ball is to make sure that moving around and building a little raft are difficult and dangerous enough so as to not be plausible.

There is little you can do to stop the hero from killing themself on purpose however.